# Why don't I get the same result from these two code blocks?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why I'm not getting the same result form these two code blocks.

```
var line = "";
var counter = 0;
while (counter < 10) {
  line = line + "#";
  print(line);
  counter = counter + 1;
}
```

-

```
var NumSym = "";

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){

print(NumSym + "#");

}
```

Also I'm not sure what to call these blocks, expressions perhaps? Thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: You're not changing the value of `NumSym` in your second example >_>

Comment: It's supposed to be half a pyramid made out of # symbols.

Comment: <_< yeah I found my mistake....... I didn't really see it that easily.

Answer (score 1):

In second block, you are not storing value in variable so string concatenation will not work. So single # sign will be displayed each time.

Second block could be:

```
var NumSym = "";

  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    NumSym = NumSym + "#"
    console.log(NumSym);

}
```

To understand the concept of expressions. **[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide)** for topics 'Expressions and operators' and 'statements'.

Comment: I got it to work with this code...

var NumSym = "";
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
NumSym += "#";
print(NumSym);
}


Also, are these examples called just "blocks"?

Comment: @RufioLJ: Not really, you could call them _blocks_ but since JS doesn't have block-scope, it's rather pointless. I'd just refer to them as a `while`-loop and a `for`-loop respectively

Answer (score 1):

In the first `while-loop` example, you concatenate an additional hash (`#`) to the `line` string constant on each iteration:

```
line = line + "#";
```

Whereas in the second `for`-loop, you don't:

```
print(NumSym + "#");
```

In the second line, you print the current value of `NumSym` (which is `''`), and add a single `#` to that, so it'll print ten `#`. In other words: the value of `NumSym` is never changed.
BTW: in JS there's a general consensus that *"things"* that start with an UpperCase letter are object constructors, variables start with lower-case letters. Just so you know...

Since I've noticed you've asked this question a couple of times in the comments:

A statement is a "line" of code that *"1 or more things"*:

```
var foo;//stmt declaring a variable, called foo (implicitly initialized to undefined)
var foo = 'bar';//stmt declares AND assigns a string constant to the variable
var foo, bar, x = 1;//statement, consisting of 4 expressions
```

An Expression is a meaningful part of a statement:

```
var result = 2*123;//where 2*123 is an expression, result = 2*123 is, too
while(result > 123)//while([expression])<-- an expression resolves in a value (true or false)
```

A block is somewhat vague in JS, basically all code wrapped up in curly's could be called a block, but this might cause confusion for those who are used to languages like C++, where each block has its own scope.

```
int x = 0;//global
int main()
{
    int x = ::x;//function scope
    for (int x=0;x<10;x++)
    {//x == loop scope, ::x == global x
        printf("In loop x: %d, outer x: %d\n",x, ::x);
        ::x = x%2 == 0 ? x : ::x;
    }
    if (x == 0)
    {
        printf("true\n");//will show up on the screen!
    }
    return x;
}
```

Output:

> In loop x: 0, outer x: 0
>   In loop x: 1, outer x: 0
>   In loop x: 2, outer x: 0
>   In loop x: 3, outer x: 2
>   In loop x: 4, outer x: 2
>   In loop x: 5, outer x: 4
>   In loop x: 6, outer x: 4
>   In loop x: 7, outer x: 6
>   In loop x: 8, outer x: 6
>   In loop x: 9, outer x: 8
>   true

This is not the case in JS, that's why I'd refer to your code examples as loops, instead of blocks. Simply because I feel that a *block* should *shield* or *block* the manipulation of variables that are declared outside of the block itself. But I think it's more of a personal thing.

Comment: Thanks for the last tip. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you're alwalys printing out `NumSym` (which is always the empty string, because you're never changing it from its initial value) plus one `#` character.

In other words, a series of lines each containing one `#`.

To make it equivalent to the first block, you would use something like:

```
var NumSym = "";
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NumSym = NumSym + "#";
    print(NumSym);
}
```

Comment: Yup I figured it out at the last minute. Damn I swear I read it many times before actually posting this question.. and I got it after the 100th time when already posted lol. Thanks for the time man. Also are those lines just called "blocks" ? Aren't they expressions?

Comment: @RufioLJ, there should be an optional ten-minute delay after posting before questions become visible to anyone other than the poster, so that you can delete it without looking silly. I've done that a few times as well :-) No, I'm not _really_ suggesting that since, even if a question now seems obvious to the poster, it _still_ may be of help to others.